# Pillow Attribute Error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I want to set up an imagestream from my rbpi to my server.

So I would like to setup a network stream discripted in the http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes1.html#streaming-capture.

This worked well, but now I want to save the captured Image.

-> (modified the server script)

```
import io
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image

# Start a socket listening for connections on 0.0.0.0:8000 (0.0.0.0 means
# all interfaces)
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)

# Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
try:
    while True:
        # Read the length of the image as a 32-bit unsigned int. If the
        # length is zero, quit the loop
        image_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        if not image_len:
            break
        # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image
        # data from the connection
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))
        # Rewind the stream, open it as an image with PIL and do some
        # processing on it
        image_stream.seek(0)
        image = Image.open(image_stream)
        print('Image is %dx%d' % image.size)
        image.verify()
        print('Image is verified')
        im = Image.new("RGB", (640,480), "black") #the saving part
        im = image.copy()
        im.save("./img/test.jpg","JPEG")
finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

But it returns me following errorcode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stream.py", line 33, in <module>
    im = image.copy()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 781, in copy
    self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 172, in load
    read = self.fp.read
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may have to call `image.load()` before the `image.copy()`. The docs make that sound unnecessary, but Pillow has been known to have bugs...

Comment: This reduces the Error in line 781. But the second error is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a raspberry-pi, but decided to see if I could reproduce the problem anyway. Also, for input I just created an image file on disk to eliminate all the socket stuff. Sure enough I got exactly the same error as you encountered. (**Note:** IMO you should have done this simplification yourself and posted an MCVE illustrating the problem (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the SO Help Center).

To get the problem to go away I added a call to the `image.load()` method immediately after the `Image.open()` statement and things started working. Not only was the error gone, but the output file seemed fine, too.

Here's my simple test code with the fix indicated:

```
import io
import os
from PIL import Image

image_filename = 'pillow_test.jpg'

image_len = os.stat(image_filename).st_size
image_stream = io.BytesIO()
with open(image_filename, 'rb') as image_file:
    image_stream.write(image_file.read(image_len))
image_stream.seek(0)
image = Image.open(image_stream)
image.load()  # <======================== ADDED LINE
print('Image is %dx%d' % image.size)
image.verify()
print('Image is verified')
im = Image.new("RGB", (640,480), "black") #the saving part
im = image.copy()
im.save("pillow_test_out.jpg","JPEG")
print('image written')
```

The clue was this passage from the [pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) for the `PIL.Image.open()` function:

> This is a lazy operation; this function identifies the file, but the file
>    remains open and the actual image data is not read from the file until you try
>    to process the data (or **call the `load()` method**).

Emphasis mine. You would think the `image.verify()` would make this unnecessary because it seems like verifying the "file" would require loading the image data in order to check its contents (according to that method's own [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.verify), which claims it "verifies the contents of a file"). My guess is this is likely a bug and you should report it.